# What is the maximum cofactor of elliptic curve used for ECDSA?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I know that the cofactor of curve 25519 is 8. Is it the maximum factor in the existing curve used for ECDSA?

Comment: What is the reason behind this question?

Comment: just curiosity~

Comment: Similar https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/why-would-anyone-use-an-elliptic-curve-with-a-cofactor-

Answer (score 4):

The [X9.62 ECDSA standard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.202.2977&rep=rep1&type=pdf) does not specify a bound on permissible cofactors (though it only records how to validate cofactors up to about $\sqrt p/4$). The [Certicom SEC1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) document only allows cofactors up to $2^{t/8}$ where $t$ is the bit size of the field. In theory then, quite large cofactors might be in use somewhere. In practice people almost always preferred to use Weierstrass curves with cofactor 1 a) for efficiency and b) to avoid possible weaknesses with unverified parameters. I believe that all of the NIST standard curves have cofactor 1 for example. By contrast Curve 25519 allows a cofactor so that it can have a compatible [Edwards curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve) representation (Edwards curves are more efficient and have better anti-sidechannel properties; their order over prime fields is always divisible by 4 however). Similarly Curve 448 has a cofactor of 4 and an Edwards form.

ETA: [kelalaka](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/18298/kelalaka) points out that 25519 pre-dates Edwards curves; it was a happy coincidence that it was Edwards compatible.

In [pairing-friendly cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography) larger cofactors can be quite common as there are very stringent conditions on the curve order. Such curves are however not generally used for ECDSA.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea!

Comment: Maybe we can call this as the Swan Song of the [Harold Edward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Edwards_(mathematician)) died last year :(

Comment: X9/NIST/SECG $F_p$ curves (secp#r aka P-# random and secp#k Koblitz) have cofactor 1; the $F_{2^m}$ curves (sect#r aka B-# random and sect#p aka K-# Koblitz) which now are rarely used have 2 or 4. See SEC2 and FIPS186-2 or higher. Brainpool (only $F_p$) are also 1.